# Eagar Loading A Nested Object Inside of a User Object

Tags: php, object, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to work with with my ProfilesController so that it'll return all the neccessary data I need for it to so I can pass it to my view after it is returned from my database. With it show method in my controller returning data from my User model  and then eagar loading the data from the profile I want it to make sure it adds the nested social links array inside the profile array.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller {

    /**
    * Display the specified resource.
    *
    * @param int $id
    * @return Response
    */
    public function show($username)
    {
        $user = User::with('profile')->whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail();
        return $user;

        return view('profile', compact('user'));
    }

}

<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserProfile extends Model {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $table = 'user_profiles';

    /**
     * Assigns the relationship between a user proifle and their social  links.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function social_links()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfileSocialLinks');
    }
}
```

This is the JSON object that current gets returned.

```
{
    id: 1,
    created_at: "2015-03-28 21:25:19",
    updated_at: "2015-03-28 21:25:19",
    deleted_at: null,
    profile: {
        id: 1,
        user_id: 1,
        bio: "This is just my personal biography!",
        created_at: "2015-03-28 21:25:34",
        updated_at: "2015-03-28 21:25:34",
        deleted_at: null
    }
}
```

I want the JSON object to appear as such:

```
{
    id: 1,
    created_at: "2015-03-28 21:25:19",
    updated_at: "2015-03-28 21:25:19",
    deleted_at: null,
    profile: {
        id: 1,
        user_id: 1,
        bio: "This is just my personal biography!",
        created_at: "2015-03-28 21:25:34",
        updated_at: "2015-03-28 21:25:34",
        deleted_at: null,
        social_links {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add nested relations, you need to specify them in `with` this way:

```
 $user = User::with('profile.social_links')->whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail();
```

This way you will load profiles and also social_links for profiles.

Alternatively you could probably create custom `toArray` method in `Profile` class to load all required relationships.

Answer (score 1):

The model relationship does not execute the query, but it does give you access to [dynamic properties](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#dynamic-properties).

You can add a join clause to your query to enable you to get the subquery properties into your result.

Comment: I"m not sure I understand how that would be performed.

Comment: Joins are something you do need, documented in [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#joins) but the (other) answer with User::with('profile.social_links') - is probably easier.